# Pandas.read_csv not reading full header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that has positions and velocities of particles saved like this:

```
x, y, z, vx, vy, vz
-0.960, 0.870, -0.490, 962.17, -566.10, 713.40
1.450, 0.777, 2.270, -786.27, 63.31, -441.00
-3.350, -1.640, 1.313, 879.20, 637.76, -556.24
-0.504, 2.970, -0.278, 613.22, -717.32, 557.02
0.338, 0.220, 0.090, -927.18, -778.77, -443.05
...
```

I'm trying to read this file and save it as a Pandas dataframe in a script with read_csv. But I would get errors when calling any column except the first one

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'y'

I would never get the error for the 'x' column, so I wrote a snippet to see if I could figure out where the reading error was stemming from.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('snap.csv')
print data
print data.x
print data.y
```

The console correctly prints out

```
          x      y      z       vx       vy       vz       
0    -0.960  0.870 -0.490   962.17  -566.10   713.40   
1     1.450  0.777  2.270  -786.27    63.31  -441.00   
2    -3.350 -1.640  1.313   879.20   637.76  -556.24  
3    -0.504  2.970 -0.278   613.22  -717.32   557.02  
4     0.338  0.220  0.090  -927.18  -778.77  -443.05 
...
```

meaning it is assigning the columns the correct names. Then

```
0      -0.960
1       1.450
2      -3.350
3      -0.504
4       0.338  
...
```

showing it can take one of the columns out correctly. But then it throws the error again when trying to print the second column

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'y'

I then looped through data.itertuples() to print the first row individually in order to see what that looked like, and it confirmed that the names were only being assigned to the first column and none of the others.

```
Pandas(Index=0, x=-0.96, _2=0.87, _3=-0.49, _4=962.17, _5=-566.1, _6=713.4)
```

There aren't any other problems with the data. The values all correspond to the right index. It's just that the names are not being assigned correctly and only the first column can be called by name. I tried putting single quotes around each column name, and that shows the exact same errors. 
I know there are ways I might be able to work around this such as assigning the names in the read_csv function, but I'm curious as to what the issue could actually be so as to avoid having this happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring column names when you create the data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(“file.csv”), columns=[“x”, “y”, “z”, “vx”, “vy”, “vz”])
```

Comment: This works using names=[..] but I'm still curious as to why read_csv is only reading in the name of the x column in my original code. I can't figure out a reason for it.

Comment: Why because all other column names are starting with a space

Comment: result of df.columns

Index(['x', ' y', ' z', ' vx', ' vy', ' vz'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Anoop why are the columns not just named ' y' and ' z' then instead of 'y' and 'z'? I removed the spaces from the header and my original code works now thanks

Comment: pd.read_csv has a parameter named 
skipinitialspace : boolean, default False
Skip spaces after delimiter.

If this was set to True, it would have worked

Comment: I think what we need to think is..Had  read.csv imported the columns as is (with the initial space), your subseqent df operations would have caused trouble anyways...
I might have gone crazy calling column y but not working...because of a space prefixed to it..
I think overall it is simply making the df and its subsequent operations elegant..

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv("snap.csv",names =["x", "y", "z", "vx", "vy", "vz"])
```